# ERROR (dkms apport) when upgrading kernel from 3.0.8 to 3.9.4

Tags: 13.04, updates, kernel

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 and I am experiencing a lot of issues like:

- Crash when waking up from suspend
- Crash when logging out of session
- Random crashes in Unity (not in i3wm)
- Slow boot
- Some errors during boot

I've been working on this for a while, and someone suggested that it must be some sort of low level error and told me to try and update the kernel before I file a bug report.

But when I try to update to the mainline kernel from kernel.ubuntu.com I get this error when installing the headers-generic-amd64 file:

```
martinux@g580:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 226254 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic 3.9.4-030904.201305241545 (using linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic (3.9.4-030904.201305241545) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.9.4-030904-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.9.4-030904-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.9.4-030904-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
```

Here is make.log

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom for kernel 3.9.4-030904-generic (x86_64)
sø. 02. juni 16:18:29 +0200 2013
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1578:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1578:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘wl_cfg80211_ops.set_tx_power’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1579:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1579:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘wl_cfg80211_ops.get_tx_power’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: In function ‘wl_update_bss_info’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2025:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘cfg80211_put_bss’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:33:0:
include/net/cfg80211.h:3302:6: note: expected ‘struct wiphy *’ but argument is of type ‘struct cfg80211_bss *’
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2025:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘cfg80211_put_bss’
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:33:0:
include/net/cfg80211.h:3302:6: note: declared here
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.o] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic'
```

I'm on a Lenovo g580 and would like to know if there is a possible fix for this or if I should just file a bug report and install 12.10 in stead.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, the new kernel was in fact installed even though I got an error.

I was also advised (I did not try it) to try

```
 sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

to avoid the error.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open bug in the bcmwl package:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1157880

So if you have a Broadcom wifi card, you need to downgrade to 3.8.0 to get the wireless driver building.